# What type of estimates are needed to use Hahn Banach?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A:H\rightarrow H$ be a densely defined operator in the set of smooth functions of compact support. Moreover assume  an estimate of the following form is available:

$$||v||_{H}\le(||v||_{\infty}+1)||Av||_{H}$$ for all $v\in C_{o}^{\infty}$.

and $||v||_{\infty}$ is the sup norm of $v$

If  we defined a functional $K:A(C_{o}^{\infty})=\operatorname{ Range}A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by

$$K(Av)=(f,v)_{H}$$

where $f$ is an  element of $H$.

Can $K$ be extended to $H$ by applying Hahn-Banach?

My reasoning is the following:

$$|K(Av)|=|(f,v)_{H}|\le ||f||_{H} ||v||_{H}\le||f||_{H}(||v||_{\infty}+1)||Av||_{H}$$

with the operator norm satisfying $||f||\ge||K||_{op}$

Is this correct?

More generally if the estimate is of the form $$||v||_{H}\le (g(v)+C)||Av||_{H}$$
where $g(v)$ is a positive function and $C$ a positive constant that does **not**  contain the norm of $v$ in $H$ can we conclude that we can apply Hahn-Banch to extend $K$ to the whole H.

Comment: Line 6 ;What is  $A(C_0^{\infty})$ ?   Line 7: What is $ f $  and  what does  $A$  have to do with the RHS?

Comment: $A(C^{\infty}_{0})$ is the range of $A$. $f$ is an arbitrary element of $H$ . Notice that the estimate allows to be sure that $K$ is well defined.

Comment: How does $f$ relate to $A$? Why can you find such $f$? Are you just assuming that? Use `\operatorname{ }` for "Range". I think you mean $f(v)$ does not *depend*, not *contain*.

Comment: Thanks,  I have edit the question now.  I am defining $K$ by taking and arbitrary $f$.

Comment: You do not have $\sup \{ |K(AV)|/||Av||_H :0\ne Av\}<\infty$. You have $|K(A(v)|/||Av||_H\leq ||f||_H(1+||v||_{\infty})$ for $Av\ne 0$.

Comment: Agree. What about using this definition instead  $\|K\|_{op} = \inf\{c \ge 0 : |K(Av)| \le c\|Av\| \}$?

Comment: @yess: it is the same...

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your $A$ is linear. Since the domain of $A$ is a subspace, you get for every $\lambda > 0$
$$\lambda \, \|v\|_H \le (\lambda \, \|v\|_\infty + 1) \, \lambda \, \|A\,v\|_H.$$
Dividing by $\lambda$ and the limit $\lambda \searrow 0$ yield
$$\|v\|_H \le \|A\,v\|_H.$$
Now, you can use your arguments to show $\|K(Av)\| \le \|Av\|$.